# Setting Number of Puma Workers on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

Why do I have 4 Puma workers if I've set WEB_CONCURRENCY=3 in my Heroku config?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468059/puma-app-instances-on-heroku/34468509#34468509), I learned that New Relic calls Puma workers "app instances".

Here is my `puma.rb` configuration:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 1)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Valid on Rails 4.1+ using the `config/database.yml` method of setting `pool` size
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Heroku config:

`WEB_CONCURRENCY: 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puma has one master process.
It does not deal with request. It monitors and manages(restart or something) workers.

If you set 3 concurrency, there are 4 process. 3 workers(managing request) and 1 master precess(managing workers)

Comment: Thank you.  Does the master process use as much memory as a worker?